# Why does this error occur when it shouldn't?

Tags: javascript, html, if-statement

I've been writing a script that will check for reflective XSS vulnerabilities. I'm having an error on a part that checks if you have "http://" or "https://" in your URL and '*' in the place of queries. However, when I put `https://google.com/#q=*", it results in`ERROR! MISSING 'http://', OR 'https://'!`. Here's my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

  <head>

    <title>Slingshot.XSS</title>

  </head>

  <body style="font-family:monospace;" align="center">

    <h2>Slingshot.XSS</h2>
    <h3>Slingshot.XSS is a script that launches pre-loaded XSS payloads at a target to test its vulnerabilities.</h3>
    <h4>Please report all issues to <a href="https://github.com/keeganjk/slingshot.xss/issues"></a> or contact me at keeganjkuhn@gmail.com.</h4>
    <a href="github.com/keeganjk/slingshot.xss" style="font-family:monospace" align="center">Source Code / Learn More</a>
    <br />

    <h4>Enter a URL with <b>*</b> in the place of query.</h4>
    <h5>Example: https://www.google.com/#q=*</h5>
    <input type="text" id="myText" placeholder="Enter a URL"> <button onclick="myFunction()">Submit</button>

    <p id="demo">No Submitted URL</p>

    <script>

      function myFunction() {

        var x = document.getElementById("myText").value;

        // Error check
        if ( !x.includes("*") && ( !x.includes("http://") || !x.includes("https://") ) ) {

            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "ERROR! MISSING \'*\' IN PLACE OF QUERY, \'http://\', AND \'https://\'!";
            x = false;
            return 0;

        }

        if ( !x.includes("*") ) {

            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "ERROR! MISSING \'*\' IN PLACE OF QUERY!";
            x = false;
            return 0;

        }

        if ( !x.includes("http://") || !x.includes("https://") ) {

            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "ERROR! MISSING \'http://\', OR \'https://\'!";
            x = false;
            return 0;

        }

        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;

      }

    </script>

  </body>

</html>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `if ( !x.includes("http://") || !x.includes("https://") )` It can't be *both* `http` and `https`. You need an `&&`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've refactored your function to show how you can reduce the complexity of the code when you separate the validation logic from the rendering of the errors.

```
function myFunction() {
    var errors = [];
    var x = document.getElementById("myText").value;

    if (!x.includes("http://") && !x.includes("https://")) {
      errors.push('missing HTTP or HTTPS');
    }

    if (!x.includes("*")) {
      errors.push('missing * in place of query')
    }

    // render the errors
    if (errors.length) {
      x = 'Error: ' + errors.join(', ') + '!';        
    }

    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

  <head>

    <title>Slingshot.XSS</title>

  </head>

  <body style="font-family:monospace;" align="center">

    <h2>Slingshot.XSS</h2>
    <h3>Slingshot.XSS is a script that launches pre-loaded XSS payloads at a target to test its vulnerabilities.</h3>
    <h4>Please report all issues to <a href="https://github.com/keeganjk/slingshot.xss/issues"></a> or contact me at keeganjkuhn@gmail.com.</h4>
    <a href="github.com/keeganjk/slingshot.xss" style="font-family:monospace" align="center">Source Code / Learn More</a>
    <br />

    <h4>Enter a URL with <b>*</b> in the place of query.</h4>
    <h5>Example: https://www.google.com/#q=*</h5>
    <input type="text" id="myText" placeholder="Enter a URL"> <button onclick="myFunction()">Submit</button>

    <p id="demo">No Submitted URL</p>

    <script>

      function myFunction() {
        var errors = [];
        var x = document.getElementById("myText").value;

        if (!x.includes("http://") && !x.includes("https://")) {
          errors.push('missing HTTP or HTTPS');
        }
        
        if (!x.includes("*")) {
          errors.push('missing * in place of query')
        }

        if (errors.length) {
          x = 'Error: ' + errors.join(', ') + '!';        
        }


        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;

      }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 3):

You check if http is not in OR https is not in. One of both will always be true. 
Perform the checks one after another... for example

Answer (score 0):

You need to write the `if` condition correctly.

Change the condition **from**

`if ( !x.includes("http://") || !x.includes("https://") ) {`

**to**

`if ( !(x.includes("http://") || x.includes("https://")) ) {`

In this way, you raise the error only when the url doesn't contain either `http://` or `https://`

**Complete Code:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

    <html>

      <head>

        <title>Slingshot.XSS</title>

      </head>

      <body style="font-family:monospace;" align="center">

        <h2>Slingshot.XSS</h2>
        <h3>Slingshot.XSS is a script that launches pre-loaded XSS payloads at a target to test its vulnerabilities.</h3>
        <h4>Please report all issues to <a href="https://github.com/keeganjk/slingshot.xss/issues"></a> or contact me at keeganjkuhn@gmail.com.</h4>
        <a href="github.com/keeganjk/slingshot.xss" style="font-family:monospace" align="center">Source Code / Learn More</a>
        <br />

        <h4>Enter a URL with <b>*</b> in the place of query.</h4>
        <h5>Example: https://www.google.com/#q=*</h5>
        <input type="text" id="myText" placeholder="Enter a URL"> <button onclick="myFunction()">Submit</button>

        <p id="demo">No Submitted URL</p>

        <script>

          function myFunction() {

            var x = document.getElementById("myText").value;

            // Error check
            if ( !x.includes("*") && ( !x.includes("http://") || !x.includes("https://") ) ) {

                document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "ERROR! MISSING \'*\' IN PLACE OF QUERY, \'http://\', AND \'https://\'!";
                x = false;
                return 0;

            }

            if ( !x.includes("*") ) {

                document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "ERROR! MISSING \'*\' IN PLACE OF QUERY!";
                x = false;
                return 0;

            }

            if ( !(x.includes("http://") || x.includes("https://")) ) {

                document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "ERROR! MISSING \'http://\', OR \'https://\'!";
                x = false;
                return 0;

            }

            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;

          }

        </script>

      </body>

    </html>
```